# How do I clip / use globalCompositeOperation = "desination-out" to exclude 2 circles from my Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I am trying to figure out `CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out` in order to create a "Fog of War" effect.

Given this example

https://jsfiddle.net/wobzpjLL/

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// a green background box
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150); 

// a line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.stroke();

// Fog of war
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150); 

// Here I want two circles that shows the background (green & line)

// text
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```

How do I create two circles that excludes the black overlay, so that the user can see the green background and the line, within those two circles, black everywhere else (hence creating a fog of war effect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using masks

#### Fog of war using compositing

The easiest way to achieve the masking is by creating a offscreen canvas and render the mask onto that. Then when animating you render the world and then apply the mask with `"destination-in"`. You can use the canvas CSS background as the fog (as done in demo) or you can render the fog over the top with `"destination-over"` also shown in demo using the text.

#### Layered rendering

Personally and for performance (if code is needing every break it can get) I would avoid `globalCompositeOperation` and render the fog over the world by creating the inverse of the mask in the demo. This adds only the one extra render call and no need to change composite operations

#### Example using composition

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function createCanvas(){
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = 300;
  c.height = 150;
  c.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  return c;
}

// draw game world on offscreen canvas
function drawBackground(ctx){
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150); 

  // a line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#08A";
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// create and render world
var bGround = createCanvas();
drawBackground(bGround.ctx)


// create mask 
var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,60,0,0,0);
grad.addColorStop(0,"rgba(0,0,0,0.0)");
grad.addColorStop(0.2,"rgba(0,0,0,1)");
grad.addColorStop(1,"rgba(0,0,0,1)");

var mask = createCanvas();
mask.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,75,75);
mask.ctx.fillStyle = grad;
mask.ctx.beginPath();
mask.ctx.arc(0,0,60,0,Math.PI*2);
mask.ctx.fill();
mask.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,225,75);
mask.ctx.beginPath();
mask.ctx.arc(0,0,60,0,Math.PI*2);
mask.ctx.fill();
document.body.appendChild(mask);

// draws the fog
function drawFog(ctx,x){
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.drawImage(mask, x, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
function loop(time){
  ctx.drawImage(bGround,0,0);
  drawFog(ctx,Math.sin(time / 1000) *20);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50); 
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="background : black;" ></canvas>
<div>Pre rendered offscreen mask shown below for display only.</div>
```

Comment: This is extremely useful, thanks! In your comment, you wrote that you would avoid `globalCompositeOperation` due to poor performance, but create an inverse mask instead? Do you have an example of that, or something I can search the web for?

Comment: Or do you mean, to create a second Canvas. Make it all black, but with that 2x transparent and draw that image on top of the primary canvas? hm.

Comment: @corgrath Yes what you  describe  in the second comment.